# How do you run php post only on button press

Tags: php

Whenever I refresh the page the modal automatically opens even though I don't press the button. Is there a way in my if statement to make it only open when the button is pressed? Thanks!

I am very new to PHP so my code may not be efficient.

```
<?php
                            include_once 'includes/database.php';
                            if ($_SESSION['renterID'] == 0){
                              $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, paymentID, paymentAmount, paymentDate, paymentPaid FROM renter, payment WHERE renter.renterID = payment.renterID ORDER BY paymentDate ASC";

                            } else {
                              $sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName, paymentID, paymentAmount, paymentDate, paymentPaid FROM renter, payment WHERE renter.renterID = payment.renterID AND $_SESSION[renterID] = renter.renterID";
                            }
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo
                                "<tr>
                                    <td>$row[paymentID]</td>
                                    <td>$row[firstName] $row[lastName]</td>
                                    <td>$row[paymentAmount]</td>
                                    <td>";echo date ('F d, Y', strtotime($row['paymentDate'])); echo "</td>";
                                    if ($_SESSION['renterID'] == 0) {
                                      if ($row['paymentPaid'] == '0') {
                                        echo "<td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'>Paid</i></a></td>";
                                      } else {
                                        echo "<td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'>Paid</i></a></td>";
                                      }
                                    } else {
                                    if ($row['paymentPaid'] == '0'){
                                      echo "

                                          <td class='text-center'><button href='#' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' id='payNowButton' name='payNowID' value='$row[paymentAmount]'><i class='fa fa-usd' aria-hidden='true'>Pay Now</i></button></td>

                                      ";
                                    } else {
                                      echo "<td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'>Paid</i></a></td>";
                                    }
                                  }
                                echo "</tr>";
                              }
                            } else {
                              echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>No payments at this time</td></tr>";
                            }


    <?php
  if(isset($_POST['payNowID'])){
    $totalAmount = $_POST['payNowID'];

    echo "<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#payNowButton').click(function() {
        $('#pay_now').modal('show');
      });
    });
    </script>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: The button ID should be unique which may not be possible if the DB query returns multiple rows. In this case, JS will not react properly as expected.

Comment: Flagged as "why doesn't my code work?"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a php problem, rather this is a jQuery problem. You are setting in jQuery that it must show the modal on document ready. That is because it shows up.
Replace your jQuery method with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.btn').click(function() {
   $('#pay_now').modal('show');
  });
});
```

This way the modal will be shown only if you click the button.

Comment: tried this but the modal doesn't show up at all now. I think the problem now is that when the button is pressed it reloads the page and by the time it gets to jQuery to check the button isn't pressed. Could be wrong as I'm new to both. Thanks!

Comment: Now I understand the problem... but you just want to show the modal just by pressing the button calling php? This isn't the best way to do it. Remove php, just use jQuery with my code.

Comment: That makes sense. The only problem is that I have those 2 buttons that are created through as while loop and only the first button shows the modal but I also need the php to run so that it can set the $totalAmount based on what button is pressed

Comment: If you can edit your answer and add the loop we can check if we can do it in Javascript if possible. Because using php for these things is a waste of server resources!

Comment: We as a community shouldn't answer this type of question it just encourages lazy people not to do their own debugging.

Comment: @catbadger I wouldn't have posted this if I hadn't already tried multiple things before

Comment: @catbadger you are right, but I think that he is just a beginner. Helping him will not harm anyone, I think

Comment: @b_dejonge I don't get the problem here because it seems that should work anyway. I don't know from where you get all that data (It seems database). Simply make the Javascript show up even if the "payNowID" isn't set. Don't worry, Javascript will not execute unless you really press the button. This is a normal practice.

Comment: @Optiroot yes that would work but the thing is that when the form submits (to send the $totalAmount from the row to the modal) it refreshes the page therefore not detecting that the button was pressed.

Comment: @Optiroot Thanks for your help. You were correct in saying that using php was not the best choice. I was able to use javascript and get the element value by id and post it that way.

Comment: Glad that it works now! Congrats. If you want you can set the answer as the correct one.